# Why is no suitable method found to override?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, background-service

I am writing a background service in .NET Core and in my `ExecuteAsync` method I'm getting this error:

> ERROR: 'DerivedBackGroundPrinted.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken)': no suitable method found to override
> BackGroundTask.Demo

Here is my class:

```
namespace BackGroundTask.Demo
{
    public class DerivedBackGroundPrinted : Backgroundservice
    {
        private readonly IWroker worker;

        public DerivedBackGroundPrinted(IWroker worker)
        {
            this.worker = worker;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            await worker.DoWOrk(stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

My `Backgroundservice` class:

```
namespace BackGroundTask.Demo
{
    public class Backgroundservice
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like its expecting a Demo() method in the BackGroundTask class. Have you tried giving it what it expects?

Comment: Your local BackgroundService does that have the member to be overridden. You are most likely looking for [Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.BackgroundService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.backgroundservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) and your derived class is using the one defined within the same namespace. Either remove the local class or use the explicit namespace of the framework's built-in background service

Answer (score 1):

Your local BackgroundService

```
namespace BackGroundTask.Demo
{
    public class Backgroundservice
    {
        // No members have been defined within the class
    }
}
```

does that have that member to be overridden, so the error message is accurate. It is possible your local class was autogenerated by mistake.

You are most likely looking for [Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.BackgroundService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.backgroundservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) and your derived class is using the one defined within the same namespace.

Either remove the local class and add a `using` namespace

```
namespace BackGroundTask.Demo
{
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

    public class DerivedBackGroundPrinted : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly IWroker worker;
        public DerivedBackGroundPrinted(IWroker worker)
        {
            this.worker = worker;
        }
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            await worker.DoWOrk(stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

or use the explicit namespace of the framework's built-in background service

```
namespace BackGroundTask.Demo
{
    public class DerivedBackGroundPrinted : Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly IWroker worker;
        public DerivedBackGroundPrinted(IWroker worker)
        {
            this.worker = worker;
        }
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            await worker.DoWOrk(stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```